# Routing from one child route to another and then back to 1st child route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my application there is a scenario where I would like to route from 'createcontrol' route to 'createform' route (which is a sibling of 'createcontrol'). This works as expected and 'createform' screen is loaded.
Now if a certain condition is met I would like to route to 'createcontrol' route but this is not working. This happens ONLY WHEN 'createform' route was routed from 'createcontrol'.

Is there some issue where you route back to the sibling which routed you in the first place?
This is my definition for the routes

```
{ 
    path: 'projects/learningconsole', 
    component: LearningConsoleComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'createdocument', component: CreateDocumentComponent, outlet: 'r1' },
        { path: 'createform', component: CreateFormComponent, outlet: 'r1' },
        { path: 'editform', component: EditFormComponent, outlet: 'r1' },
        { path: 'createcontrol', component: CreateControlComponent, outlet: 'r1' }
    ]   
}
```

Also note that I get no error in the console. The screen remains as it is and even the url doesn't change to indicate r1:createcontrol as I would expect.

Below is my code to route to createcontrol screen:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/projects/learningconsole/(r1:createcontrol)');
```

I do not think the problem is with any components as I am able to initially route to createcontrol screen without any issue.

To summarize in simpler words:
consider there are 3 sibling routes A,B,C.
Routing from C to A  works.
Routing from A to B works.
Only Routing from A to B to A doesn't work.

Comment: This may be unrelated, but I've encountered it.  If you are using the new `*ngIf` syntax with `ng-templates` and one of the templates is several lines long, the application will error and become unresponsive, but nothing will indicate an error in the console.  Just from looking at your routes, they look fine.  The problem most likely is somewhere else, in the 'createform' component or parent.

Comment: Can you please provide more code about how are you doing the routing(like the places you are using routerLink) so we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I agree with @KerimEmurla, you need to provide your routing code so we have a complete picture of what you're attempting. Further more, what does "Not working" mean?  Are you receiving an error, a blank screen, or an altogether different route?

Comment: @KerimEmurla : I have updated my question to include my routing code. I get no error. The screen stays at createform and even the url doesn't change.

Comment: @TylerJennings: I am not using ng-templates at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely exists with the relativity of your routes.  Essentially, the first attempt at routing is probably occurring from outside your outlet.  The send sibling to sibling is occurring from inside the outlet, so you don't need to specify the parent route `'projects/learningconsole'`. Try this instead (for sibling to sibling only):

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('(r1:createcontrol)');
```

If this does not work, another potential solution would be to specify relativity (you will probably have to tweak this, since I don't have a complete picture of your component):

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('(r1:createcontrol)', { relativeTo: this.routeParams });
```

This alternative approach would require you to inject the `ActivatedRoute`:

```
constructor(
        private routeParams: ActivatedRoute,
```

**UPDATE:**

There is potentially a third solution to this that would require less routing knowledge.  However, this is clearly the less desirable approach.  I cannot speak to the efficacy of this solution, as you haven't provided details on your project structure.  Try updating your routes to what I've placed below:

```
[{ 
    path: 'projects/learningconsole', 
    component: LearningConsoleComponent
 },
 { path: 'projects/learningconsole/createdocument', component: CreateDocumentComponent, outlet: 'r1' },
 { path: 'projects/learningconsole/createform', component: CreateFormComponent, outlet: 'r1' },
 { path: 'projects/learningconsole/editform', component: EditFormComponent, outlet: 'r1' },
 { path: 'projects/learningconsole/createcontrol', component: CreateControlComponent, outlet: 'r1' }
]
```

Comment: Earlier atleast I was able to route to createcontrol from another component using my given code for routing. If I substitue that with what you suggested, even that is not working. The screen stays at current screen and no error.
My original problem was coming to createcontrol from a route, which in the first place was routed to by createcontrol. ONLY in such a scenario was I not able to route to createcontrol. Now with what you suggested I am not able to route to createcontrol at all !

Comment: @PoonamSomani It sounds like you ignored the note about trying it "(for sibling to sibling only):".  Because if you had, your original route would not have been affected.  I would recommend reading up on the concept of routing.  However, I'll update the answer with something that may be a little easier for you (though, less desirable).